# can we pass a variable containing our url in jquery $.get() from a php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

hi i have a graph created from a .csv file using the jquery $.get(). but currently i am passing hardcoded file name as first argument to my get() method. My function is in a file named index.js and is like this

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.get('myproject.csv', function(data) { ..... } 
    ....... });
```

but what i want is to pass a variable which contains the file name so that it can have any file name instead of 'myproject.csv'

```
    $.get($filename, function(data) {
```

where $filename could be any filename passed.  i don't have much idea about jquery and all so not sure.

Now the main thing is that i have a .phtml file where i have this javascript file incorporated as inline script. So I have no idea how to pass the variable from this .phtml file to this javascript file. 
My .phtml file:

```
      <head>.......</head>
      <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/PFFd02/public/media/js/modules/appone/index/index.js"></script>      // this is where i need to pass my variable. 
      ...........
      </body>
```

any help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all. I figured out a simple way of passing the variable from php file to my js.

What i did was i created a view variable in my controller file and assigned it a string containing div tag as follows:

```
    $this->view->filename = "<div id=\"filename\" style=\"display:none\">".$file."</div>";
```

where $file is the variable that contains my filename which i have to pass to javascript. Now in my zend view i did something like this:

```
    <?php echo $this->filename ?>
```

which is making the filename available to my view where i have to run that javascript. Then in my javascript function i initialized a variable like this:

```
        var file = $('#filename').text();
        $.get(file, function(data) {
```

and so i got the variable passed from php file to my javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var filename=<?=json_encode($filename)?>;
$.get(filename, function(data) {
```

This sets the Javascript variable `filename` to the value of the PHP variable `$filename`, and calls `$.get(filename)`.

Comment: but where would i specify my $filename. I have a .phtml file which calls this javascript file and my .phtml file contains this $filename variable.

Comment: `<?=json_encode($filename)?>` echoes the $filename variable in a way that is understandable by javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get(<?php echo json_encode($filename) ?>, function(data) {
```

using json_encode ensures that any JS metacharacters in the filename won't "break" your script.

Comment: json_encode alreay quotes strings, no need to add quotes around `<?php echo json_encode($filename) ?>` ;)

Comment: thanks, but i am not sure where to specify the values of $filename. Since i have a helper function called in my zend layout file which is calling this .js file. Now i want to somehow specify the value of the variable in my zend layout file i.e. .phtml file so that when the helper function calls the javascript file, this variable is passed to the javascript file.